# Probable database character encoding error with chinese multilingual translation

Tags: database, i18n-l10n

I am doing translation of a site's content from English to Chinese but upon saving the translation for a node(I previously did a few blocks) I get the error below. My search led me to questions like [configuring drupal to use unicode characters](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50868/configuring-drupal-to-use-unicode-characters) but I just need another perspective to see if this is a different type of problem (because I already translated blocks and menus with the chinese characters) and how would I solve it.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value:
'\xF4\x8F\xB0\x80\xE5\x8D...' for column 'field_overview_value' at row 1:
INSERT INTO {field_data_field_overview} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, 
bundle, delta, language, field_overview_value, field_overview_format) VALUES
(:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, 
:db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5,
:db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7); Array ( 
[:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 1547 
[:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 7588 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => product     
[:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und
[:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 
<h3> 业内最可靠的视频服务器平台</h3> <p>作为视频服务器和存储系统的市场领导品牌,
SpectrumTM 是一 体化制作和播出系统以及完全基于文件的工作流程的理想平 台。
模块化的系统架构可以保证最大的稳定性和灵活性,使 得全球的制作人和电视专业人员都选用 
Spectrum 来实现高效 的无带化工作流程。这个系统可以完全胜任于下列范围的工 作:</p> <ul>
<li> 从模拟到数字的设备改造,完全遵从国家标准</li> <li> 从磁带到硬盘播出的改造,升操作效率
</li> <li> 从标清到高清的升级,升广播质量</li> <li> 从单频道播出升级到多频道播出,遵从市场需
求</li> </ul> <p>整合了广播视频技术领域的专家与信息技术方面的最佳实 践,Spectrum 供了最具
性价比,开放和灵活的视频服务 器,满足播出环境的严苛需求。 ￼￼￼￼ ￼<br /> &nbsp;</p> <h4> 主要特点
</h4> <ul> <li> 独立的可扩展通道、存储、带宽并且保证冗余,智能、高 性价比架构。</li> <li>
在已有系统中添加新的组件即可实现高清或者 3D 播出, 确保完全的投资保护。</li> <li> 在传送、
演播室制作、新闻和体育集锦、分布式播出工作 流程中是最好的基于文件的解决方案。</li> 
<li> 可以从几百种播出应用中自由选择,基于开放标准和开放 API。</li> </ul> <p>&nbsp;</p>
<h4> CNN - Aquisition, Playout and Storage Case Study</h4> <p><iframe 
allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360"      
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KBrAqR7P8DU?rel=0" width="640"></iframe></p>
 <p>&nbsp;</p> <h4> NAB 2013 Enter...the Spectrum!</h4> <p>
<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="360"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/p82nloy1JT4?rel=0" width="640"></iframe></p>
[:db_insert_placeholder_7] => full_html ) in 
field_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 451 of 
 /var/www/html/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module).
```

Comment: What's your DBMS engine?

Comment: >> mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.52, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Comment: Any chance you can test it on mySQL 5.5 or higher? [See this](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/interviews/alexander-barkov.html) - in 5.5 it was significantly improved (and even more so in 5.6) **but** I'm not really sure it will solve your case.

Comment: @Molot I tried it on my localhost 5.5.9 and got the same error

Comment: What confuses me most is that I paste the same text in a block and it doesn't display an error...

Comment: Just seen your answer. That explains a lot. Guess these characters did not end up here, got cut by your browser or Stack's engine.

Comment: I see a few "" characters above that might be the problem and these are not chinese symbols

Comment: So it was my browser that obscured them :(

Answer (score 1):

Ok So the problem was actually not the Chinese text but that I was copy-pasting from a PDF file that seemed to have injected some unwanted characters in the body that the database was rejecting.