# changing unicode characters in a module

Tags: database, installation, configuration

There are hundreds of records in a database that are in `windows-1256` charset, I want to read these data and convert them to `utf8` then insert them in a new table, to read these data I need to change the MySQL unicode to `latin1` and convert the data to `utf8`. from this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50868/configuring-drupal-to-use-unicode-characters) I successfully did this. 
Now I need to insert these data into database and their charset must be `utf8`, the problem is `$database` variable in `settings.php` have this configuration

```
$databases = array (
  'default' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
    array (
      'database' => 'DB_NAME',
      'username' => 'PASSWORD',
      'password' => 'PASSWORD',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
      'collation' => 'latin1_general_ci',
      'pdo' => array(
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES latin1",
      )
    ),
  ),
);
```

and in `database/mysql/database.inc` line 57 changed to this:

```
if (!empty($connection_options['collation'])) {
  $this->exec('SET NAMES latin1 COLLATE ' . $connection_options['collation']);
}
```

so because of this new database configuration, insertion the converted records (to `utf8`) doesn't provide the desire result (because MySQL is `latin1` now), I need to reset the database configuration to its origin just before inserting the data. how do I can do this?

---

UPDATE:

the only solution I have found so far, is to create another database in `utf8` and using external connection move the data into there !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) run query 
`ALTER DATABASE DB_NAME DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci` 
on your data base

2) change line

> 'collation' => 'latin1_general_ci'

in settings.php to

> 'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci'

and line

> PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES latin1"

to

> PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"